# Tableau Nested IF Statement including STRING and INTEGER

Tags: loops, if-statement, tableau-api, nested-loops, nested-lists

I am trying to count distinct count  of specific items which have alphanumeric (STRING ID)
that matches a certain criteria, i.e uncollected invoices that had been outstanding for more than 45 days

{FIXED [Invoice ID] : (IF([INOVICE CATEGORY] = 1 THEN
(IF [Median Invoice age] > 45 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)}

But I am getting an error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if any of those fields are already aggregated, but the above was missing the END to the first IF and the first IF had an unnecessary "(".

Try the below and see if it works or if your error message changes.

```
{FIXED [Invoice ID] : (
IF [INOVICE CATEGORY] = 1 THEN (
IF [Median Invoice age] > 45 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 END)}
```

You may have to aggregate your main IF statement.